# create facebook event, add cover photo and invite friends using c#

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a Winforms C# application which creates a Facebook event with a cover photo and invites friends to this event.

I successfully created an event using this code:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(GenericSingleton<LoggedInUser>.Instance.AccessToken);
Dictionary<string, object> createEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
createEventParameters.Add("name", "event test new");
createEventParameters.Add("start_time", "2014-05-15T02:30:00+0000");
createEventParameters.Add("description", "inviting to all………");
createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "OPEN");

JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
```

How do I change/insert a cover photo for this event?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
createEventParameters.Add("cover_url", "http://www......./MyNewEvent.jpg");
```

Also, how do I invite friends to this event?

Thanks!

Comment: `JsonObject resul` looks like a typo, shouldn't that be `JsonObject result`? (It doesn't really matter if you're consistent throughout your code; just pointing it out in case you didn't notice.)